# Summary, reorganizing and "flatten" the entire multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I have an array like :

```
Array(
  [0] => Array([range]=>1-10 [count]=>3 [type]=>A)
  [1] => Array([range]=>11-20 [count]=>6 [type]=>A) 
  [2] => Array([range]=>21-30 [count]=>5 [type]=>A)

  [3] => Array([range]=>1-10 [count]=>5 [type]=>B)
  [4] => Array([range]=>11-20 [count]=>3 [type]=>B)
  [5] => Array([range]=>21-30 [count]=>8 [type]=>B)

  [6] => Array([range]=>1-10 [count]=>4 [type]=>C)
  [7] => Array([range]=>11-20 [count]=>3 [type]=>C)
  [8] => Array([range]=>21-30 [count]=>6 [type]=>C)

  [9] => Array([range]=>1-10 [count]=>3 [type]=>D)
  [10] => Array([range]=>11-20 [count]=>7 [type]=>D)
```

And then I am trying to regroup/remake the array depends on their `type` and the expected output would be like :

```
Array(
  [0] => Array([type]=>A [1-10]=>3 [11-20]=>6 [21-30]=>5)
  [1] => Array([type]=>B [1-10]=>5 [11-20]=>3 [21-30]=>8)
  [2] => Array([type]=>C [1-10]=>4 [11-20]=>3 [21-30]=>6)
  [3] => Array([type]=>D [1-10]=>3 [11-20]=>7)
)
```

I have tried `array_column` but isn't what exactly I want...

[Example Here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7223d3797c4f02c7bb82d69157c0b5e76e3c0aca)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I simply loop through the entire array and then check with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) if the result array already has an innerArray with the same type (e.g `$result["A"]`), if not I add the type as value to the inner array (.e.g. `$result["A"]["type"] = "A";`).

After this check I simply add the `range` and `count` to each type (e.g. `$result["A"]["1-10"] = 3;`)

At the end I simply reindex the entire `$result` array with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
<?php

    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($result[$v["type"]]))
            $result[$v["type"]]["type"] = $v["type"];
        $result[$v["type"]][$v["range"]] = $v["count"];
    }
    $result = array_values($result);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => A
            [1-10] => 3
            [11-20] => 6
            [21-30] => 5
        )
    //...

)
```